# npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE errno 134 / 9009

Tags: angular, npm, build, jhipster, errno

I tried to build an app with JHipster with an angular frontend but when I run the the following command to launch everything:

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

I get an `ELIFECYCLE` error.

I've looked at many topics on that error but I've not found a good solution for my case.

I tried lots of things such as:

- increase the memory with command
- increase-memory-limit
- `node --max_old_space_size=8192`

... etc. but it's always impossible to build.

> ```
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.9.1:npm (webpack build dev) on project sam:
>     Failed to run task: 'npm run webpack:build' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException:
>     Process exited with an error: 9009 (Exit value: 9009) -> [Help 1]
> [ERROR]
> ```

[Screen of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdEuw.png)

Can someone can help?

Comment: Why are you using `mvn eclipse:eclipse`? Are you using the Eclipse IDE? If that's the case, have you checked [this](https://www.jhipster.tech/configuring-ide-eclipse/) guide?

Comment: Yes iam using eclipse and i didn't checked the guide befor!
Thanks for your help ! 
i didn't saw that link befor, i follow what they say on it and its working now